# Windows authentication doesn't work on subdomain, why?

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I have a .NET MVC application with Windows authentication, so I have this in `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

I'm running it on my local IIS, say `http://localhost:84/` when I browse this url the authentication popup appears and I can login - everything works.

Now I added `ntlm.localhost` to my `hosts` file and added a binding in IIS, when I browse `http://ntlm.localhost:84/` the auth pops up but it doesn't let me in even if I enter correct username/password. It just pops up again and again no matter what I enter.

It doesn't set any cookies and I've read about Windows authentication but didn't see any references to subdomains and urls.

Why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Comment: Windows has strict restriction on how authentication works. Please go to event log and see the related section to see what is the error logged there.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this IIS forum post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1086863.aspx?NTLM%20Authentication%20not%20working%20when%20on%20same%20server%20as%20IIS) which led me to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

I had to add my custom host name (with subdomain) to `BackConnectionHostNames` in registry [Method 1] of 2 proposed solutions.